# Replace only text inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like:

```
<div id="one">
       <div class="first"></div>
       "Hi I am text"
       <div class="second"></div>
       <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to change only the text from "Hi I am text" to "Hi I am replace" using jquery.
This might be easy but I am not able to do it.

Using `$('#one').text('')` just empties the whole `#One` div.

Comment: It might be helpful to make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Use $('#one').find('.first').text('Hi I am replace'); instead of $('#one').text(); or you can directly access the element and replace text by using $('.first').text('Hi I am replace');

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Text shouldn't be on its own. Put it into a `span` element.

Change it to this:

```html
<div id="one">
       <div class="first"></div>
       <span>"Hi I am text"</span>
       <div class="second"></div>
       <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#one span').text('Hi I am replace');
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question, who did not say that they have control over the HTML.

Comment: this is worked but how can sure to executed or not ? can i run exception if blank or tag changed? in unsuccessful bindings because this div created by code.from REST or database

Comment: this is wrong. .text will tail the text to existing one.

Answer (score 151):

Find the text nodes (`nodeType==3`) and replace the `textContent`:

```
$('#one').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Hi I am text','Hi I am replace');
});
```

Note that as per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) you can replace the hard-coded `3` in the above with `Node.TEXT_NODE` which is much clearer what you're doing.

```js
$('#one').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
}).each(function(){
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('Hi I am text','Hi I am replace');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">
       <div class="first"></div>
       "Hi I am text"
       <div class="second"></div>
       <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this doesn't require you to change the html!

Comment: @Jamiec FWIW I love this answer because it allows replacements without worrying about borking the markup/scripts etc.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  Sometimes we work in situations that don't allow changing the HTML (ie SharePoint). Thanks

Comment: Why not replace `3` with `Node.TEXT_NODE` to make the snippet clearer?

Comment: @Paul thanks, it is much clearer so I've included it as a note on this old answer.

Comment: Hello, it does not work for me with my example https://jsfiddle.net/xpcf49mh/

Comment: @LeninZapata This only looks at the children of the selected element, to search all the way down the DOM you'll need something more recursive (or select the element you want directly)

Answer (score 20):

You need to set the text to something other than an empty string. In addition, the .html() function should do it while preserving the HTML structure of the div.

```
$('#one').html($('#one').html().replace('text','replace'));
```

Comment: While this would work in this case,  I do not like this option because if you were replacing the word "first" with the word "second" or just 'i' with '' it would mess up your tags

Answer (score 11):

If you actually know the text you are going to replace you could use

```
$('#one').contents(':contains("Hi I am text")')[0].nodeValue = '"Hi I am replace"';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5rWwh/

Or

```
$('#one').contents(':not(*)')[1].nodeValue = '"Hi I am replace"';
```

`$('#one').contents(':not(*)')` selects non-element child nodes in this case text nodes and the second node is the one we want to replace.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rWwh/1/

Comment: From `jQuery 1.8.3` `$('#one').contents(':not(*)')` will select nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you can't change HTML. Very primitive but short & works. (It will empty the parent div hence the child divs will be removed)

```js
$('#one').text('Hi I am replace');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one">
  <div class="first"></div>
  "Hi I am text"
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This removes all of the child divs of #one

Comment: @ScotNery thank you, I have updated the answer. (Although it technically answers this particular question) I'm assuming other than wrapping the text with a tag that has an id, it'd be quite challenging. Only other thing is to match a string to replace, but it's really fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is keep that element, change the text, then append that element back

```
const star_icon = $(li).find('.stars svg')
$(li).find('.stars').text(repo.stargazers_count).append(star_icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but **the text was the first node inside the parent element.** In this case you can do something like this and it's really quick:

```
// find the children elements
 termsChildren = $('#one').children()

// replace the text, then re-append the children element.
 $('#one').text(' "Hi I am replace" ').append(termsChildren)
```

Otherwise, you have to specify which children have to go before the text, and which afterwards:

```
// find the children elements
 termsChildren = $('#one').children()

// remove all the content
 $('#one').text(' ')
// append the first child element
 $('#one').append(termsChildren[0])
// add the new text and then the other children
 $('#one').text(' "Hi I am replace" ').append(termsChildren.slice(1))
```

Answer (score -1):

When you replace the plain text of an element with jQuery, you **cannot** put the plain text on its own, or else it will clear and/or replace the entire element. You should put all the plain text inside a `<span>` element:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#change-btn").click(function() {
    $("#one").children("span").text("Hi I am replace");
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Import CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="m-2">
  <div id="one">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <span>Hi I am text</span>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-2" id="change-btn">Click to change text</button>
</div>
```