# Replace div string Jquery

Tags: jquery

I've this code :

```html
<div>
 Hello world.
 <a href="#">test</a>
 <a href="#">login</a>
</div>
```

I want to replace "hello world." With "Hello everybody !".

I try this :

```
$('div').text('Hello everybody !');
```

But it does not work, thanks for your help !

Comment: Wrap the "Hello World" in a span, then target it with `$('div > span')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace only text inside a div using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867269/replace-only-text-inside-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

$('div').html($('div').html().replace('Hello world.', 'Hello everybody !'));

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="greeting">Hello world.</div>
    <a href="#">test</a>
    <a href="#">login</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#greeting").html("Hello everybody !");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('div').html($('div').html().replace('Hello world.', 'Hello everybody !'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.fn.myfilter = function(textToReplaceWith)
{
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {

       if(this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) != "") // nodeType = 3 represents textual content in an element
           $(this).replaceWith(textToReplaceWith);         
    });  
}

$('div').myfilter('Hello everybody !');
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/8/

You may also pass params to replace a specific text dynamically.

```
$.fn.myfilter = function(textToReplace,textToReplaceWith)
{
  $(this).contents().filter(function() {

       if(this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) == textToReplace) 
           $(this).replaceWith(textToReplaceWith);         
    });  
}

$('div').myfilter('Hello world.','Hello everybody !');
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/9/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('div').html($('div').html().replace('Hello world.', 'Hello everybody !'));
```