# jQuery string replacement and a link

Tags: jquery, replace, hyperlink

I replace text inside table cells using text.replace

```
$('td:contains("ABC ")').text(function(_, text) {
  return text.replace(/ABC /g, 'XYZ');
  return text.replace('ABC ', 'XYZ');
});
```

for such a cell `ABC <a href="http://example.com">Text</a></td>`

For some reason when I apply that replacement, the links inside the cells become inactive to mouse click. What's the cause and is it possible to change that?

Comment: Please add fiddle represent/reproduce your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace only the text node:

```
$('td:contains("ABC ")').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).each(function() {
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/ABC /g, 'XYZ');
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11867485/909180)