# jQuery - Replace Text(Slogan) with HTML(Logo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to replace a specific Slogan(Text) with an Image(HTML) via jQuery on every Page, except the Slogan in the E-Mail-address.

First i tried this, but the problem was it was outputing text and not HTML

```
jQuery("p").text(function () {
    return jQuery(this).text().replace("Slogan", '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo.svg" alt="Slogan">'); 
});
```

Second i tried this following code, but it also replaced `alt="Slogan"` of existing elements and broke the site:

```
jQuery(function($){
$("p").html(function(i,o) {
   return o.replace('Slogan','<img class="script-logo" src="/wp-content/uploads/logo.svg" alt="Slogan">');
 })
});
```

Now i use this code, but it is not really save to use when a other person fills the content, and im afraid that it will not work as wanted.

```
jQuery(function($){

 $('p:contains("Slogan")').html(function(i,o) {
   return o.replace('Slogan','<img class="script-logo" src="/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo.svg" alt="Slogan">');
 })
});
```

Is there any proper and save way to archive what i want to do?

fyi: i dont select only the Paragraph like in the example, i also select all Headlines and ankertags.

Had some troubles with the requested HTML example, hopefully this helps and is enough:

```
<!--- Nav example --->

<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_btn3-container menuButton vc_btn3-inline">
<a class="scroll vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-default" href="/live/" title="" data-hover="/wp-content/uploads/menu-Slogan-video3.jpg">Slogan 0-5A Bearbeitung</a>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!---  Content Example --->
<div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <div class="vc_btn3-container menuButton vc_btn3-inline">
<a class="scroll vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-flat vc_btn3-color-default" href="/live-zerspanung/" title="" data-hover="/wp-content/uploads/menu-Slogan-video3.jpg">Slogan UE110-5A Simultan Bearbeitung</a>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--- Footer Example --->

<div class="column one-fourth"><aside id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">           <div class="textwidget"><div class="image_frame image_item no_link scale-with-grid alignnone no_border"><div class="image_wrapper"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="http://www1.Slogan.at.5.your-server.de/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo.svg" alt="Slogan-logo"></div></div>

<hr class="no_line" style="margin: 0 auto 20px;">

<h5>Unternehmen der Slogan GmbH</h5>
<p class="big&quot;" style="margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;"></p>
<p class="big&quot;" style="margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;">E-Mail: <a href="mailto:holding@Slogan.eu">holding@Slogan.eu</a></p></div>
        </aside></div>


<div class="copyright">
        <p>© 2016 <img class="script-logo-Slogan" src="/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo-white.svg" alt="Slogan"> Slogan Gmbh - Lorem | <a href="/impressum">Impressum</a> | <a href="/datenschutz">Datenschutz</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the HTML in which you want to run the replace?

Comment: Html added, hopefully its enough and helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

     var sloganHTML = '<img class="script-logo" src="/wp-content/uploads/logo.svg" alt="Slogan">';
     function onlyTextNodes() { 

         return this.nodeType === 3;

     }
     function replaceSloganWithImage() {

         this.html( this.html().replace( "Slogan", sloganHTML ) );

     }
     $( "p" ).contents()
         .filter( onlyTextNodes )
         .each( replaceSloganWithImage );

} );
```

(Thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11867485/275501)

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough without jQuery:

```
Array.toArray(document.querySelectorAll('p'))
  .forEach(function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
        'Slogan', 
        '<img class="script-logo" src="/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo.svg" alt="Slogan">'
    );
  });
```

Or with ES2015 syntax:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('p')]
  .forEach(el => 
     el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(
      'Slogan', 
      '<img class="script-logo" src="/wp-content/uploads/Slogan-logo.svg" alt="Slogan">'
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCyJr/137/) for that. I use `.click` to trigger the event

```
  $('p').html(function (index, text) {
      this.innerHTML = text.replace('Slogan', "<img src='$1.png'>")
  });
```