# How to change a text which does not have any tag to it?

Tags: jquery

Could somebody help me change value of text for below code.  When i tried to change it will remove Input element tag completely i need only "  English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ "text to be changed. As am working on some frame work i cant cant add span to my text.

```
 <div class="Main">
   <label class="lbl" for="1111" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px; color:#000000;width:49%;"> Preferred Language / ಆದ್ಯತೆಯ ಭಾಷೆ   <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>     <div class="cont" style="margin-left:50%;width:50%;">
   <div class="optiongroup column_2 noborder"> 
   <div class="Main"> <label class="lbl" for="1111_1" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
   <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="1" name="1111" id="1111_1" required="true" aria-required="true">&nbsp; English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ</label></div> 
   <div class="Main"> <label class="lbl" for="1111_2" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
   <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="2" name="1111" id="1111_2" required="true" aria-requienter code herered="true">&nbsp; Kannada / ಕನ್ನಡ</label></div>
   <label class="error" for="1111" style="display: none;"></label> </div> 
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace only text inside a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867269/replace-only-text-inside-a-div-using-jquery)

Comment: Please add you code that you tried to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Using `contents()` will return text nodes so that you can work with them. Then you convert it to a DOM node to be able to interact with it and, finally, update the text without touching the HTML tags.

OR

You can get the radio putton, convert it into a DOM element and get the next sibling - which is your text node - and update the textContent.

I added 3 different ways of doing it in the code snippet

```js
//$('label[for="1111_1"]').contents().last()[0].textContent=' Your Text Here';
//$('#1111_1').parent().contents().last()[0].textContent=' Your Text Here';
$('#1111_1')[0].nextSibling.textContent = ' Your Text Here';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Main">
  <label class="lbl" for="1111" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px; color:#000000;width:49%;"> Preferred Language / ಆದ್ಯತೆಯ ಭಾಷೆ   <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
  <div class="cont" style="margin-left:50%;width:50%;">
    <div class="optiongroup column_2 noborder">
      <div class="Main"> <label class="lbl" for="1111_1" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
   <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="1" name="1111" id="1111_1" required="true" aria-required="true">&nbsp; English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ</label></div>
      <div class="Main"> <label class="lbl" for="1111_2" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
   <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="2" name="1111" id="1111_2" required="true" aria-requienter code herered="true">&nbsp; Kannada / ಕನ್ನಡ</label></div>
      <label class="error" for="1111" style="display: none;"></label> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `document.body.innerHTML`.

Like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ", "")
```

```js
function Remove(){
     document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ", "")
}
```

```html
    <div class="Main">
        <label class="lbl" for="1111" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:14px; color:#000000;width:49%;"> Preferred Language / ಆದ್ಯತೆಯ ಭಾಷೆ   <span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
        <div class="cont" style="margin-left:50%;width:50%;">
            <div class="optiongroup column_2 noborder">
                <div class="Main">
                    <label class="lbl" for="1111_1" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
                        <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="1" name="1111" id="1111_1" required="true" aria-required="true">&nbsp; English / ಆಂಗ್ಲ
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="Main">
                    <label class="lbl" for="1111_2" style="margin-right: 0; font-family:Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000">
                        <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 0;" tabindex="1" value="2" name="1111" id="1111_2" required="true" aria-requienter code herered="true">&nbsp; Kannada / ಕನ್ನಡ
                    </label>
                </div>
                <label class="error" for="1111" style="display: none;"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button onclick="Remove()">Remove some text</button>
```